# removing multiple cloned git repositories in PuTTY

Tags: gitlab, putty

I am currently using PuTTY with gitlab and every time I switch between my personal computer I clone my git repository (I am using one main one for this class) so I can get the most recent version. However, on PuTTY (not on gitlab) it seems like I can't clone a repository I already have

`fatal: destination path '(class)' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

it creates a subfolder when I clone it and I have to keep entering these subfolders until I finally get an empty one, where I can now clone the repo. 
This might seem stupid, but is there a way to clear all of this? Clear previously cloned repos? I've been googling it a lot and can't find an answer

Comment: you should not clone your git project, you should use git pull to get the newest update, try to read this https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/ or this https://githowto.com/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that's not how you use git.

When you finished work on your PC, you `commit` and `push`, then you `pull` on your notebook within the already existing repository.

Comment: thanks so much! is there a way to delete the previous clones?

Comment: Just delete them from the filesystem? A git repository is detected by the contents of the .git subfolder.